# dangerous is not defined

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript, y tengo un problema que no logro solucionar, ya que no sé cuál es el problema en si. Intento ejecutar el código en nodeJS y me tira el error `dangerous is not defined`, `dangerous` es un atributo de un objeto. Lo que intento es filtrar una lista que contiene todos los objetos a que me muestre solo los que tienen el atributo `dangerous : true`. Esto lo quiero lograr por medio de una función que yo creo llamada `getFrom`, ya se como hacer esto por medio de un `arrObjects.filter((a) => a.dangerous`. Quiero hacerlo por medio de una función para que me quede claro el tema de definir funciones e invocarlas. Estoy casi seguro que es una novatada, cualquier ayuda o explicación la agradecería. Gracias de antemano.

***El código:***

```
var objOne = {
    heavy: true,
    usefull: false,
    dangerous: false
}

var objTwo = {
    heavy: true,
    usefull: true,
    dangerous: true
}

var objThree = {
    heavy: false,
    usefull: true,
    dangerous: false
}

arrObjects = [objOne,objTwo,objThree]

function getFrom(list,value) {
    return list.filter((a) => a.value)
}

console.log(getFrom(arrObjects,dangerous))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo tienes casi completado. Te he cambiado solo un par de cosas:

```js
var objOne = {
    heavy: true,
    usefull: false,
    dangerous: false
}

var objTwo = {
    heavy: true,
    usefull: true,
    dangerous: true
}

var objThree = {
    heavy: false,
    usefull: true,
    dangerous: false
}

arrObjects = [objOne,objTwo,objThree]

function getFrom(list,value) {
    return list.filter((a) => a[value])
}

console.log(getFrom(arrObjects,"dangerous"))
```

- En primer lugar te he cambiado la variable `dangerous` por un string que pone literalmente `"dangerous"`, ya que es una variable sin definir; de ahí el error que te está dando.
- Para acceder a la propiedad `value`, en lugar de acceder con un punto, lo he cambiado para que acceda con corchetes. El motivo es que si lo pones con un punto el motor de JS espera que haya una propiedad que se llame literalmente `"value"`. Si lo pones con corchetes, se evalúa esa expresión para determinar a la propiedad que se quiere acceder.

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Miembros
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó :)